# Port OpenGL Matrix Operations to Boost QVM

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, boost

I have some legacy code in my application that was using OpenGL to do some quick matrix math.  It seems like this could be replaced by boost::qvm, but examples of usage are scarce.  The basic code is:

```
#include <boost/qvm/mat.hpp>
#include <boost/qvm/mat_operations.hpp>

void foo()
{
    auto heading = 90.0;
    auto speed = 10.0;
    auto xComponent = 0.0f;
    auto yComponent = 0.0f;

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glLoadIdentity();

        glRotatef(static_cast<GLfloat>(heading), 0, 1, 0);
        glTranslatef(0, static_cast<GLfloat>(-speed), 0);

        float modelviewMatrix[16];
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewMatrix);

        xComponent = modelviewMatrix[2*4 + 0];
        yComponent = modelviewMatrix[0];
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

So I was wondering if anyone had any quick ideas to share about how to implement this with boost::qvm?

So, the boost::qvm version should be something very similar, but I'm not sure how to do the rotation and translation as the API is fairly different from OpenGL.

```
void foo() 
{ 
    auto heading = 90.0;
    auto speed = 10.0;
    auto xComponent = 0.0f;
    auto yComponent = 0.0f;

    boost::qvm::mat<double, 4, 4> matrix;
    boost::qvm::set_identity(matrix);

    // rotate?

    // translate?

    // get components?
}
```

**Final Code:**

The code ended up looking like this after this question:

```
#include <boost/qvm/mat.hpp>
#include <boost/qvm/vec.hpp>
#include <boost/qvm/mat_operations.hpp>
#include <boost/qvm/map_vec_mat.hpp>

// ...

boost::qvm::mat<double, 4, 4> matrix;
boost::qvm::set_identity(matrix);
boost::qvm::mat<double, 4, 4> rotation = boost::qvm::roty_mat<4>(deg2rad(heading)); 
boost::qvm::vec<double, 3> v{{0.0, -speed, 0.0}};
boost::qvm::mat<double, 4, 4> translation = boost::qvm::translation_mat(v);
```

Comment: Is boost::qvm a requirement? Have you considered the [glm library](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html)?

Comment: Boost is a requirement only so that we don't have to add another external dependency.  I was not aware of glm, but since it appears to be header only, it might be a possibility.  I'd like to see if a qvm solution is reasonable here in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rotation** and **translation** matrices can be obtained using boost (examples):

```
boost::qvm::rotx_mat<4>(3.14159f); // rotation on x axis by PI radians

vec<float,3> v={0,0,7};
mat<float,4,4> tr=translation_mat(v); // translation by 7 units on z axis
```

You will get the **combined transformations** by multiplying your modelview matrix with these matrices.

Then, **getting components** is a matter of reading the needed values from your modelview matrix (your modelview can be the matrix that you have already declared with the line `boost::qvm::mat<double, 4, 4> matrix;`).

Answer (score 1):

It's best to not put intermediate results from [view proxies](http://boostorg.github.io/qvm/view_proxy.html) like `translation_mat` or `roty_mat` into a `mat<>` object. Either capture intermediate results in `auto const &` or just multiply them in-line as shown below. This avoids the creation of any temporaries.

```
auto heading = 90.0;
auto speed = 10.0;
auto xComponent = 0.0f;
auto yComponent = 0.0f;
{
    using namespace boost::qvm;
    double const v[3] = {0,-speed,0};
    auto const & result = translation_mat(vref(v)) * roty_mat<4>(deg2rad(heading));
    xComponent = A02(result); //Not sure if this should be A20 instead
    yComponent = A00(result);
}
```